# Get color name from a text input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a color name from text input using js but the code doesn't work at all. (I'm using p5.js btw)

my HTML :

```
<input placeholder="Type color name OR type 'Random' for a random tint!" style="width: 340px; border-radius: 5px; border: 3px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid; background-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);" id="colors"></input>
```

my JS :

```
    colorss = "";
function preload() {

}
function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
    canvas.position(480, 300);
    video = createCapture(VIDEO);
    video.hide();

    colorss = document.getElementById("colors").value;
    console.log(colorss);
}
function draw() {
image(video, 0, 0, 400, 400);
}
function submit() {
    r = random(255);
    g = random(255);
    b = random(255);
    if(document.getElementById('colors').value == "Random") {
    tint(r,g,b);
    } else{
        tint(colorss);
    }
}
```

I'm using p5.js too and I tried using a different variable, so i don't understand why it isn't working... pls help

Comment: Use the debugger. Ctrl-Shift-I will bring it up.

Comment: What is `random()` ?

Comment: `<input />` is self closing, for one. You do know there is `<input type='color' />`, right? It's a bad practice to not scope your variables, in JavaScript. Huge code smell. What's your real goal?

Comment: so basically what i want to do is : 1) get the color from the text input 2) put that color is a variable 3) use the color variable to add tint to the live camera view

Comment: When you load the page  your input field is empty, so it won't set the color. If you want to set the color later you need an event handler on the `change` event, or nothing will happen. You appear to have a `submit()` function, but it's not clear how or even if that's ever called. There's clearly stuff missing here which might be relevant. See [mcve]

Comment: oh wait... i forgot to add the function part...

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `setup()` function is executed ones when the page is opened and than `submit()` is executed once the submit button is clicked.

So what you have here is you execute `setup()` and load value of your input field into `colorss` variable. At this point the value is an empty string.

Then when you submit the form, you are using the value of `colorss` variable which is still an empty string.

What you need to do is use something like this:

```
tint(document.getElementById("colors").value);
```

Also, please declare variable with `var`, `let` and/or `const`

Comment: thank you sooooo muchhhhhhhhh! it finally works! i didn't think of doing it that way but ty!